# Julia, conditionally substitution of individual elements

Tags: arrays, julia, probability, substitution

I asked a question about this earlier but may be over-complicating the issue. Given an array:

```
a = [3,4,3,6,3];
```

what code do I need to execute the following:

if the individual element of `a == 3`
then with a probability `(p=0.67)`, change the value to 9
else leave the element as a 3

Thx. J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this would be the shortest way to achieve what you want:

```
a[findall(x -> x==3 && rand()<=0.67, a)] .= 9
```

Comment: quick one.  This works well for this example, but for some reason when I specify "a" directly as 1d array, which is subset from a 3d array as such, it doesn't change the original array.  I thought it would?  I can do it in two steps but don't understand why this doesn't work.     The overall 3d array is called "Pop" and this is to do the substitutions on the bottom row  of dim3(1)  `Pop[end, :, 1][findall(x -> x==3 && rand()<=0.67, Pop[end, :, 1])] .= 9`   Thx. J

Comment: `Pop[end, :, 1]` creates a copy of the column and later you are mutating just the copy. In order to write to the original data use a `view`. More or less this will do the trick `(@view Pop[end, :, 1])[findall(x -> x==3 && rand()<=0.67, Pop[end, :, 1])] .= 9`

Comment: Again Thx. one more complication .... can I @view a second array, essentially, if and when Pop[end, :, 1] is altered from 3 to 9, I want to alter the same columns in Pop[end, :, 3] to 0 sort of a reset?  3 keeps record of the days the individual was in that state, so if the state [...,1] changes, then [...,3] needs to be reset to zero.

Comment: I do not know what you mean here? Perhaps post a new question and explain the details?

Answer (score 3):

Longer but maybe clearer versions with a loop

```
for i in findall(a .== 3)
    rand() ≤ 0.67 && (a[i] = 9)
end
```

or

```
for i in findall(a .== 3)
    rand() ≤ 0.67 ? (a[i] = 9) : continue
end
```

Comment: Thx. @Benoit Pasquier, same challenge as I describe above for code that Przemyslaw gave, when I try to substitute in "Pop[end, :, 1]" for a, to do a direct insert of the 1d array subset from the original 3d array, it fails.  Any idea why that is?  Also should the ≤ be <= ?  I want the probability to be exactly 0.67,  ≤ suggests "less than or equal to" 0.67 but I've likely overlooked something syntactically obvious and simple!

Comment: And the answer is the same - use a view instead of copying a column :-)